# Center absolutely positioned element over own position properties with CSS

Tags: css

I would like to center an absolutely positioned div (or other html element) over it's own top and left property with CSS if possible. By default an absolutely positioned element will align it's top left corner with the top and left property. See the diagram below where the gray box is the relatively positioned container and the red dot is the CSS position (`top: 0; left:0;`) of the blue div on the page:

[image]

I would like to know what the best option would be to center the blue div over it's own position, as in the salmon colored div on the page below.
If possible, I would like the position in percentages and not pixels.

Thus far I have only come up with a JavaScript solution. That is calculating the `width` of the child relative to it's parent and then subtracting half of that percent from the `left` position. Then doing the same for the `height` and top position. See snippet...

```js
//put elements in variables
var container = document.getElementById('main-box');
var div = document.getElementById('center-on-pos');

//get top and left in div position percentages relative to container
var div_top = (div.offsetTop / container.offsetHeight) * 100;
var div_left = (div.offsetLeft / container.offsetWidth) * 100;

//calculate how much we need to shift
var offset_top_pos = ((div.offsetWidth / container.offsetWidth) * 100)/2;
var offset_left_pos = ((div.offsetHeight / container.offsetHeight) * 100)/2;

//shift div
div.style.top = (div_top - offset_top_pos) + '%';
div.style.left = (div_left - offset_left_pos) + '%';
```

```css
body{ padding:85px; }

.container{
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  position:relative;
}

.container > div{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:rgba(255,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="main-box" class="container">
  <div id="center-on-pos"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`

```css
body {
  padding: 85px;
}
.container {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
.container > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="main-box" class="container">
  <div id="center-on-pos"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! @Nenad Vracar, just curious, and don't think there's a way, but is it possible without CSS3?

Comment: @tnschmidt if it has a known size, then negative margin will do :) `margin-top:-50px;margin-left:-50px`or just negative coordonates:`left:-50px;top:-50px;`

Comment: @GCyrillus yes https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/738/ or just negative positions https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/739/ but its not percentages as OP wants.

Comment: yep, % will not do, it takes parents size for reference

Answer (score 1):

To use only negative percentage value, you need an extra container so child an parent are same size.

```css
body {
  padding: 85px;
}
.container {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.container > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  }
.abst>div {
  margin:-50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div id="main-box" class="container">
  <div class="abst"><div id="center-on-pos"></div></div>
</div>
```